# Cypress tries to load page, instead of trying to readFile?

Tags: download, cypress

Cypress code

```
it('Check all pdf files after buying webstore items: AXQA-7446', () => {
    cy.visit(Cypress.env('base_url') + '/en/ShoppingCart/ThankYou/');
    cy.get('.ax-btn.ax-btn-secondary.ax-full-width').click();
    cy.get('.d-none.d-md-block.ax-pl-1').eq(0).click({timeout: 5000});
    cy.get('.ax-pb-2.semi-bold').children().should('have.length.gt', 0);
    cy.get('.ax-btn.ax-btn-secondary.ax-mb-1.ax-btn-sm').eq(0).click();    
    const currentDate = dayjs().format('YYYYMMDD');
    const fileName = 'Receipt_' + currentDate + '*.pdf';

    const filePath = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'cypress', 'downloads', fileName);

    // Check if the file exists
    cy.task('fileExists', filePath).then((exists) => {
      expect(exists).to.be.true; // Assert that the file exists
    });
});
```

And this is the response that I got from test.
[image: Test execution]

I would like to add test which checks if the file exists or not.

Not to load page as shown in the picture.

Could someone explain to me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is `fileExists` coming from?

Comment: From index.js 


You think there is problem? 


        cy.readFile('cypress/downloads/' + fileName).then((fileContent) => {
            expect(fileContent).to.exist;
        });

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are doing nothing wrong as far as testing the download is concerned.

I would suggest that the app is trying to display the downloaded PDF and the viewer is not compatible with Cypress test runner.

You would need to check with developers exactly how the PDF viewer is working, but one popular way is `window.open(<pdf-name>)`.

To handle that case, stub the window open function on `cy.visit()` and confirm that the function has been called. This prevents the actual viewer being activated, and your test can then confirm the download of the physical file.

Here is the broad approach in the test:

```js
cy.visit(<my-url>, {
  onBeforeLoad: (win) => {
    cy.stub(win, 'open').as('open')  // stubbing so that the viewer does not load
  }
})
...
cy.get('button').click()       // initiate the download

cy.get('@open').should('have.been.called')  // confirm the open command occurred

cy.task('fileExists', ...        // confirm the download here
```

Comment: So this is not a button, but it is rather an <a> link.

Comment: By this I mean cy.get('button').click() instead it is cy.get('a').click(). Quite sure that this is making the difference.